# Optional generic parameter and return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to build a simple delay function, but it's types aren't aligning.
I can't understand why the function doesn't implement the interface properly.
I did try with `(...): v extends void ? Promise<void> : Promise<V>`

```js
interface Delayer {
  <V>(v: V): Promise<V>;
  (): Promise<void>; // maybe something else other than void?
}

export const delay = (ms: number): Delayer =>
  (v) => v === undefined
    ? new Promise<void>(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms))
    : new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(v), ms));
```

It errors with `Type '<V>(v: V) => Promise<V> | Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Delayer'.`

Tried with packing the arguments, but they turn into `any[]`:

```js
export const delay = (ms: number): Delayer =>
  (...args) => {
    args.length === 0
      ? new Promise<void>(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms))
      : new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(args[0]), ms));
  };
```

Comment: Implementing overloads with arrow functions is not easy, see [ms/TS#47669](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47669).  You can use `any` and an optional parameter to places to make it work, or you could refactor to implementing as a function statement instead of an arrow function.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOGrdw) for both ways.  Does this meet your needs and address your question?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz cool, it works and works with "unknown"  instead of "any" which plays nice with eslint. Thanks.

Comment: @jcalz I did try with function instead of arrow functions like that, but didn't occur to try with any/unknown. Dang, I was so close.